# xml serialize deserialize

Tags: xml-parsing

I Have a dictionary data structure and i want to write it to XML like this

```
<root>
<key>House1</key>
<value>somevalue</value>
<key>House2</key>
<value>somevalue</value>
</root>
```

and i also want to get back data in my dictionary so far i have done this XmlTextWriter

```
textWriter = new XmlTextWriter("D:\\config.xml", null);
            textWriter.WriteStartDocument();
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict.Add("house", "langlat");
            dict.Add("house2", "langlat");
            XElement el = new XElement("root", dict.Select(kv => new XElement("key", kv.Key, new XElement("value", kv.Value))));
```

This is to write data to XML, but when I try to read values it gives me whole things like this Houselanglat. I want house as a key and langlat should be it's value .

Comment: No answer yet but problem solved i have figured it out myself thanx all